# Android : Not able to create directory in external sdcard in lollipop lenovo

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am tring to create directory in External sdcard, I tested my code in MI (Android M), Samsung and in lenovo (Android L). Below code works fine in all devices except in lollipop.

```
private void crateDirectory() {

    Log.d(TAG, "inside  crateDirectory()  ");
    try {
        String extPath = "";
        String base = "/storage/sdcard1/"; //lenovo
        // String base="/storage/9F44-E930/"; //  for xiaomi

        File baseFile = new File(base);
        Log.d(TAG, "baseFile.exists()   >>" + baseFile.exists());        // resulting TRUE
        String path = "Android/data/package name/files/";
        extPath = base + path;


        Log.d(TAG, "exPath   >>" + extPath);
        File myFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/MY Download");

        Log.d(TAG, "myFile  >>" + myFile.getAbsolutePath());

        File outputFile = new File(extPath, "" + myFile.getAbsolutePath());

        if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating outputFile ....");
            outputFile.mkdirs();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "outputFile.exists()   >>" + outputFile.exists() + "\n outputFile >>" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception   >>" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "end of crateDirectory()  ");
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? inside the catch block you can log the stacktrace with `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: @lelloman  No error, Just not creating Directory.  outputFile.mkdirs() is false.

Comment: you can't access external SD card in 4.4+ devices the simple way, as you try to. You have to use the Storage Access Framework for that. Don't ask me, why Google did it. I find it super stupid, but there is really no other way.